# Resnet model parameters

Tags: keras, neural-network

Below i have  snippet of python code for Resnet:

```
base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
```

What does `include_top=False, weights='imagenet'` really mean and is for?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/ResNet50):

> **include_top**:  whether to include the fully-connected layer at
> the top of the network.
>
> **weights**:  one of None (random initialization),
> 'imagenet' (pre-training on ImageNet), or the path to the weights file
> to be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

> - `include_top`: whether to include the fully-connected layer at the top of the network.
> - `weights`: one of None (random initialization), 'imagenet' (pre-training on ImageNet), or the path to the weights file to be
>   loaded.

The keyword `include_top` was nicely explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036522/defining-model-in-keras-include-top-true).
When it comes to `weights`, setting it to `imagenet` means using the ResNet50 architecture with ImageNet-trained weights.
You can use any other dataset for training and load resulting weights using this argument or just use random ones, though starting with pre-trained ImageNet might be a good idea.
Due to their transferability, networks pre-trained on ImageNet are often a good choice to start with.